# Delete API Call not working

Tags: angular, api, http

I can't seem to get my delete http call to work even though it works in Postman. I've tried debugging and it all seems to work but it still persists in my database. I really appreciate any help, I'm really at my wits end here.

Here is my html

```
 <tbody *ngFor="let item of todolist">
                    <tr *ngIf="item.state == 'Complete'">
                        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.description}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.due_Date}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <form *ngIf="item" (ngSubmit)="deleteItem(item.id)">
                                <button type="submit" class="form-control">Delete Item</button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
```

Here is my component

```
@Component({
selector: 'completeitems',
templateUrl: './completeitems.component.html',
providers: [ToDoService]
})

export class CompleteItemComponent implements OnInit {
public ID: any;
public name: string;
public description: string;
public duedate: Date;
public tags: string;
public state: string;
public todolist: ToDoList[];

constructor(private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute, private todoService: 
ToDoService, private router: Router) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchtodoitems();
}

fetchtodoitems(): void {
    this.todoService.getToDoListItems().subscribe(results => this.todolist = 
results);
}


public deleteItem(id: string) {
    this.todoService.deleteItem(id).subscribe();
    window.location.reload();
}

}
```

Here is my service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ToDoService {

constructor(private http: Http) { }

getToDoListItems() {
    return this.http.get('api/todolist')
        .map(response => response.json());
}

getItem(id: any) {
    return this.http.get('api/todolist' + id)
        .map(item => item.json());
}

addToDoListItems(item: ToDoList) {

    return this.http.post('api/todolist', item);
}

deleteItem(id: string) {
    return this.http.delete('api/todolist' + id)
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Here is my controller for my API:

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var item = this.dbContext.ToDoItems.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == 
 id);
            if (item == null)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound);
            }

            this.dbContext.Remove(item);
            this.dbContext.SaveChanges();
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status205ResetContent);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, 
 e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You passed an invalid URL to HTTP delete in your Service (you should see a 404 in the browser console).

You need to change your `deleteItem` function in your Service from:

```
deleteItem(id: string) {
    return this.http.delete('api/todolist' + id)
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

to

```
deleteItem(id: string) {
    return this.http.delete('api/todolist/' + id)
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```